# Sample size determination with three levels of sensitivity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, sample-size, clinical-trials

I am looking to conduct a one-sided cross-sectional clinical study with dichotomous (immune/not immune, with no gray area) variables and an analytical test that has specifity of 99.81 % (99.65 – 99.91 %). My sensitivity, however, will be

```
Days post PCR confirmation  Sample number (N)   Sensitivity (95 % CI)
0 – 6 days                  116                 65.5 % (56.1 – 74.1 %)
7 – 13 days                 59                  88.1 % (77.1 – 95.1 %)
≥14 days                    29                  100 % (88.1 – 100 %)
```

How can I determine my sample size if I don't know the distribution of my potential candidates in the three "post-PCR" categories? Would it be acceptable to just assume equal - meaning 1/3 per category - distribution? I will most probably be using alpha = .05 and beta = .2 but that is still an ongoing debate.
My population will be around 140 patients per week.

Thank you very much, your help is much appreciated.